# How to use a bert pretrained model somewhere else?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, pre-trained-model, bert-language-model

I followed this course https://www.coursera.org/learn/sentiment-analysis-bert about building a pretrained model for sentiment analysis. During the trining, at each epoch they saved the model using `torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'BERT_ft_epoch{epoch}.model')`. Now I want to use one of these models (the best one obviously) elsewhere, for example where a user can paste a tweet as an input and get the emotion of the writer. But I don't know how to load the model and predict, here's what I tried:

```
import torchvision.models as models
import torch

model = models.resnet101(pretrained=False)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('Models/BERT_ft_epoch15.model'), strict=False)
model_ft.eval()
output = model_ft(input) #input is a tweets list
```

I get this error: `TypeError: conv2d(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list`

Comment: You need to process your `input` to match the input for the model you are using. You have a list. I assume it's a list of tweets (string), but your model needs the input to be Tensor.

Comment: I recommend you take a look here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html , in short, had to load and initialize the same type of model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VictorZuanazzi I check it out and found this:
`model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()`

But what's the `TheModelClass` in my case I don't have any class. Take a look at the notebook here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uqeY0NjPkfypEs4L3NLMgAF2ZbFkun-j?usp=sharing

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi I tried this `model = torch.load('Models/BERT_ft_epoch15.model')
model.eval()` and got this error `AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'eval'`

Comment: @Asma, what was saved is a (ordered) dictionary containing the weights from BERT. You have to initialize the model and load the weights in the initialized model. I would recommend you going through the tutorial to understand those differences.

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi thank you I'll do the tutorial it'll probably help me understand it.

Answer (score 2):

`resnet101` and `BERT` are two totally different models. You cannot load a pretrained BERT model into resnet.

Answer (score 2):

How to define, initialize, save and load models using Pytorch.

Initializing a model. That is done inheriting the class `nn.Module`, consider the simple two layer model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Model(nn.Module)
    def __init__(self, input_size=128, output_size=10):
        super(Model).__init__()
    
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequetial(nn.Linear(input_size, 64), nn.LeakyReLU())
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(64, output_size)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.layer2(self.layer1(x))
        return y
```

The layers of the model are first initialized at `__init__()` and then we specify the operations of the forward pass in `forward()`. You can be creative there, just remember of using pytorch differenciable operations.

You initialize the model by creating an instance of the new class:

```
model = Model() # brand new instance!
```

After training your model you want to save it:

```
import torch
model = Model(128, 10) # initialization

torch.save(model.state_dict, 'model.pt') # saving state dict
```

You are not saving the model here, you are saving the `state_dict` this is an ordered dictionary that contains all the weights and biases and other parameters of your model. The reason we save the `state_dict` instead of the model directly can be found in the documentation (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html). For now, just consider it best practice.

Finally, we arrive at how to load the model. You have to initialize the model first, then load the `state_dict` from disk.

```
model = Model(128, 10) # model initialization
model.load_state_dict('model.pt')
model.eval() # put the model in inference mode
```

Notice that, when we save the `state_dict` we may also save the optimizer and the graph used for back propagation. That is useful to checkpoint the training and resume it at a later stage.

```
    # in the training loop
    torch.save({"epoch": epoch,
                "model": model.state_dict,
                "optim": optim.state_dict,
                "loss": loss}, f'checkpoint{epoch}.pt')
```

I hope that paints a cleares picture for you =)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, one more question: how to predict the output of a new tweet? What should I put inside the **forward** method?

Comment: That depends on how you model making this prediction. The *forward* method just implements the steps you have to take to transform input in output. The specific steps will depend on your model and algorithm.

Comment: Maybe consider one of those tutorials for more detailed information: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_nlp_tutorial.html